# Ember Error in Route Model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, handlebars.js

I am digging into Ember and am trying to serve a list of content to my route model. Here is my App.js code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});

    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.route('about');
        this.resource('blogs');
        this.resource('projects');
    });

    App.PROJECTS = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "SnapFoo - SVG Animation Library",
            "textone": "SnapFoo",
            "texttwo": "SVG Animation Library",
            "image": "snapfoo.jpg"
        }
    ];

    App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return App.PROJECTS;
      }
    });
```

The PROJECTS array is abbreviated in terms of content but that's the format. Now, I am trying to run my each loop in the Hanldebars template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="projects">
 {{#each}}
  <div class="project-icon">
   <span>{{textone}}</span>
   <span>{{texttwo}}</span>
   <a href="project.php?id=1"><img {{bind-attr alt="title" src="image"}}/></a>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

However, when doing this, the error I receive is
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDependency' of undefined** coming from ember.min.js.

If I remove the {{each}} loop, the error goes away which leads me to believe this has something to do with the model in the route. But any advice would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the model in your view, you are iterating over nothing `{{each}}`

You need put your variable in this case your `model`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="projects">
 {{#each model as |project|}}
  <div class="project-icon">
   <span>{{project.textone}}</span>
   <span>{{project.texttwo}}</span>
   <a href="project.php?id=1"><img {{bind-attr alt="title" src="image"}}/></a>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

I have created an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6jngg5sh/) where you can see as this code work, it's very similar what you want achieve.

Comment: This has certainly gotten me closer. However, this isn't near the syntax I was learning on CodeSchool. Is this how it is done in the Ember docs? And lastly, my bind-attr in the image will not bind anything, even a hardcoded string.

Comment: I'm following ember-cli syntax which brings with all love ES6. About the `bind-attr` here the fix 
`<a href="project.php?id=1"><img {{bind-attr alt="title" src="project.image"}}/></a>`

note that I have changed image by `project.image` which is the scope variable within the loop.

Here the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6jngg5sh/1/) updated.